# Function fired on all controller- angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scrolltop, document-body

I have this

```
  $window.onscroll = function() { scrollFunction() };

            function scrollFunction() {
                if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
                    document.getElementById("btt").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("btt").style.display = "none";
                }
            }
```

function in one contoller, but the scrollFunction gets fired even after I navigate to another page. how to limit that functionality only to the particualr page(controller).

Comment: Is it in angularjs or JavaScript?  :(

Comment: angularjs @RameshRajendran

Comment: But your code seems like JavaScript.

Comment: Put this script in one controller and use this controller in that scrolling page.

Comment: @RameshRajendran everything except `$window` :)

Comment: @tanmay yup. he should using  `angular.element()` instead of  `document.getElementById()`

Comment: @RameshRajendran and everyone. thanks :). the solution posted by aseferov works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need stop listening scroll event when controller destroy

```
angular.element($window).on('scroll', scrollFunction);

scope.$on('$destroy', function () {

  angular.element($window).off('scroll', scrollFunction);
});
```